# JS-Data error: attrs must contain the property specified by idAttribute - with hasMany relations

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jsdata, js-data-angular

**Here's the error:**
http://puu.sh/lXzja/f773fb6c9a.png

The primary key for my user model is username. The primary key for my routes is the routename. My api returns jsons inside data:{} as per jsonapi.org specs. Thus the id attribute is not in the top-level, as js-data demands. This is why I return data.data in the afterFind for 'users'. I tried to do something like that in 'routes' but it's an array of routes. 
The console log in beforeInject gives me:

[result in beforeInject](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iqpky.png)

**Here's the config:**

```
  DS.defineResource({
    name: 'users',
    idAttribute: 'username',
    basePath: apiEndpoint,

    relations: {
        hasMany: {
            routes: {
                localField: 'routes',
                foreignKey: 'username'
            }
        }
    },
    // set just for this resource
    afterFind: function(resource, data, cb) {
        // do something more specific to "users"
        cb(null, data.data);
    }
});

DS.defineResource({
    name: 'routes',
    idAttribute: 'routename',
    basePath: apiEndpoint,
    cacheResponse: true,
    relations: {
        belongsTo: {
            users: {
                parent: true,
                localKey: 'username',
                localField: 'users'
            }
        }
    },
    beforeInject: function(resource, data) {
        // do something more specific to "users"
        console.log(data);
        return data.data.routes;
    }
});
```

**Here's where I try to load my routes but get that err:**

```
  resolve: {
            user: function($route, DS) {
                var username = $route.current.params.username;
                return DS.find('users', username).then(function(user) {
                    DS.loadRelations('users', user.username, ['routes']).then(function(user) {
                        console.log(user);
                    }, function(err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    });
                });
            }
        }
```

Comment: http://puu.sh/lXzja/f773fb6c9a.png is dead. Please see [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: In case it helps someone landing on this page in the future when googling the error, I had a Mongo result going into JSData with a `"_id"` instead of `"id"`, which caused the same error as OP. The fix was to make sure that the top-level object has the `"id"` key exactly, which is pretty much the same as the solution here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not only is your data nested under a "data" field, but a "routes" field. So when you find the routes, you're trying to inject something like:

```
{
  routes: [{
    // foreignKey to a user
    username: 'john1337',
    // primary key of a route
    id: 1234
  }]
}
```

when you need to be injecting:

```
[{
  username: 'john1337',
  id: 1
}]
```

Add an `afterFindAll` on your routes resource to `cb(null, data.data.routes)`.

You'll either need to:

A) Add lots of "after" hooks to all your Resources or

B) Make the deserialization generic so it works for all Resources. Perhaps something like this?

```
DS.defaults.afterFind = function (Resource, data, cb) {
  cb(null, data.data[Resource.name])
};
DS.defaults.afterFindAll = function (Resource, data, cb) {
  cb(null, data.data[Resource.name])
};
```