# JS-Data loads data but doesn't render in view

Tags: angularjs, jsdata, js-data-angular

I have followed the js-data angular tutorial to setup js-data-angular in my current project.

**model definition:**

```
     .factory('shipmentFactory',
    function(DS) {
      return DS.defineResource({
        name:'ShipmentInstructions',
        idAttribute:'id',
        basePath:'apiEndpoint'
      }
        );
    }).run(function (shipmentFactory){})
```

**In my controller:**

```
.controller('ShipListCtrl', function($scope,shipmentFactory) {
    shipmentFactory.findAll().then(function(shipmentInstructions){
      $scope.shipments = shipmentInstructions;
      console.log($scope.shipments)
    });
});
```

In my view i attempt to iterate over the returned object using ng-repeat but nothing is displayed. I know that my endpoint is hit and data is returned because [my console displays the returned shipment object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stLuY.jpg).

The tutorial mentions how to load data into the views but looks to be for those using ngRoute. I am using ui-router in my current project and ran into more challenges when I tried to resolve that resource in that state.

That resource is used in a view that is included in another view - the template view for the state.

Just looking for some direction on how to get my data to display in my view please and thank you in advance.

**Revised shipment model:**

```
  .factory('shipmentFactory',
    function(DS) {
      return DS.defineResource({
        name:'ShipmentInstructions',
         idAttribute:'id',
            basePath:'apiEndpoint',
        cacheResponse: true,
        afterFindAll: function(data, cb){
          //extract the array from that nested property
          shipmentsArray = [];
          //forloop to push every item returned to
          for(var i = 0; i < data.shipmentInstructions.length; i++ ){
            shipmentsArray.push(data.shipmentInstructions[i]);
          }
          cb(null,shipmentsArray)
        }
      }
        );
    }).run(function (shipmentFactory){})/*makes sure shipmentFactory gets defined*/
```

Comment: Try a `$scope.$apply()` after setting the `$scope.shipments` variable

Comment: I believe that sends it into a digest loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array of shipment instructions is nested under a "shipmentInstructions" property, but by default js-data expects the data itself to be the array.

You need to extract the array from that nested property. Something like an `afterFind` or `afterFindAll` hook would be a good place to do that. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34318207/1153216) to another StackOverflow question.

Comment: Thanks that helped me out. I also had an extra data property on in my "after" hook. seems that I followed your other answer a little too closely lol thanks.